# How to install WINE in 15.10 (error with dependencies)?

Tags: wine, 15.10

I'm getting an error when installing WINE in 15.10. I already enabled required sources but it will not install on my machine. Any help? Image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

and try to install again? That should do.

Comment: @itagomo you are welcome :) thank thanking is done by upvoting in SE communities ;)